# How to animate the insert of a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift2, uibarbuttonitem

I have a simple app with a Tool Bar at the bottom.  Depending upon the context of what the user is doing, I may want various buttons visible or not in the Tool Bar.  So, in my code, I remove the `weak` modifier for the IBOutlet reference to those buttons, and I remove the non-visible buttons in `viewDidLoad`.  Great.

Now, when the context changes, I add/remove buttons as desired using

```
toolBar.items?.removeAtIndex(0)
toolBar.items?.insert(playButton, atIndex: 0)
```

Great, works well. But for aesthetics, I would like to have the button removal/insert animated.  Apparently the `animated:YES` argument from Objective-C days is gone.  Do you know, does the API support animation of the button shuffling?  Or, if not, how best to accomplish this?

Thanks!